# Skip over input stream in ATLAST forth

Tags: parsing, input, forth

I'm trying to implement a kind of "conditional `:`" in [ATLAST](http://www.fourmilab.ch/atlast/atlast2.html), the reasoning being I have a file that gets `FLOAD`ed multiple times to handle multiple steps of my program flow (I'm essentially abusing Forth as an assembler, step 1 does a first parsing for references, etc. and in step 2 the instruction words actually emit bytes).

So when declaring words for "macros" in that file, it errors out in step 2, because they were already declared in step 1, but I also can't just `FORGET` them, because that would forget everything that came afterwards, such as the references I just collected in step 1.

So essentially I need a "`:` that only runs in step 1", my idea being something like this:

```
VARIABLE STAGE

: ::
  STAGE @ 0 = IF
    [COMPILE] : ( be a word declaration )
  EXIT
  THEN
  BEGIN    ( eat the disabled declaration )
    '      ( get the address of the next word )
    ['] ;  ( get the address of semicolon )
    =      ( loop until they are equal )
  UNTIL
; IMMEDIATE

:: FIVE 5 ; ( declares as expected )

FIVE .      ( prints 5 )

1 STAGE !   ( up to here everything's fine )

:: FIVE 6 ; ( is supposed to do nothing, but errors out )

FIVE .      ( is supposed to print 5 again )
```

The traced error message (starting from `1 STAGE !`):

```
Trace: !
Trace: ::
Trace: STAGE
Trace: @
Trace: (LIT) 0
Trace: =
Trace: ?BRANCH
Trace: '
Trace: (LIT) 94721509587192
Trace: =
Trace: ?BRANCH
Trace: '
Word not specified when expected.

Trace: ;
Compiler word outside definition.
Walkback:
   ;
```

`KEY ( -- ch )` as common in some other Forths for reading a single character from the input stream ( *outside* the `::` declaration, since it's `IMMEDIATE` ) doesn't exist in ATLAST, the only related words I could find are:

- `'`: is *supposed to* read a word from the input stream, then pushes its compile address
- `[']`: like `'` but reads a word from the current line (the inside of the `::` declaration)
- `(LIT)`/`(STRLIT)`: are *supposed to* read literals from the input stream according to the documentation, I could only ever make them segmentation fault, I think they're for compiler-internal use only (e.g., if the compiler encounters a number literal it will compile the `(LIT)` word to make it push that number onto the stack)

There aren't any `WORD` or `PARSE` either, as in some other Forths.

As you can see, `'` is struggling actually getting something from the input stream for some weird reason, and it looks like `[']` is failing to capture the `;` which then errors out because it's suddenly encountering a `;` where it doesn't belong.

I suspect it actually ran `' [']`, even though it's *supposed to* work on the input stream, not the immediate line, and I'm clearly in compile mode there.

I did a [similar thing](https://gitlab.com/nonchip/mover/-/blob/master/asm.atl#L86) with conditionally declaring variables, there it was rather easy to just `[COMPILE] ' DROP` to skip a single word (turning `RES x` into `' x DROP`), but here I'm pretty sure I can't actually compile those instructions, because I can't emit a loop outside of a declaration. Unless there is a way to somehow compile similar code that recursively gets rid of everything until the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is that `'` cannot find a number. A possible solution is to use a special dummy name for the definition, instead of skip it over:

```
: :: 
  STAGE @ 0 = IF : EXIT THEN
  ' DROP \ this xt isn't needed
  " : _dummy" EVALUATE ( -- n ) DROP
;
```

Or maybe use a new name every time:

```
: :: 
  STAGE @ 0 = IF : EXIT THEN
  ' >NAME @ \ ( s1 ) \ should be checked
  ": _dummy_" DUP >R S+
  R> EVALUATE ( -- n ) DROP
;
```

But due to non standard words it might not work. Another problem is that non colon-definitions are out of the scope.

Perhaps, a better solution is a preprocessing by external means.

Comment: the issue with this is that redefining `_dummy` constitutes an error in ATLAST without `FORGET`ing it first (that's kinda the whole reason i need to do this "conditional `:` in the first place). tried to insert a `" _dummy" FIND 0<> IF " FORGET _dummy" EVALUATE DROP THEN DROP` before the `EVALUATE` line, but it doesn't seem to find+forget it. `FIND ( str -- caddr flag )` is documented as "finds the word `str`, returns the `caddr` of the word (or the string if not found), sets flag =0 if not found, <>0 otherwise". Other definitions aren't a problem and I'd rather avoid external preprocessing.

Comment: omg it works. turns out ATLAST *parses* `"` instead of having a word for it, so the issue was it couldn't find a word called "<space>_dummy". just writing them like C strings made your fix work with my `FORGET` addition.

Comment: if you want to see it in action, this assembles "print(120 NOR 30)" in my made-up CPU: https://gitlab.com/nonchip/mover/-/blob/ddb6cadd94ed989c7ab2201d6e1c5bbfd26df0ed/hello.asm

Comment: If `FORGET` can remove something excessively, you can generate a new unique name every time instead of forgetting (the answer was updated).

Comment: i'm not quite sure how that'll work, or what you mean by "removing excessively", `FORGET` forgets everything after (including) the word you tell it, so my approach, well my modification of your approach, only works because i include the same file twice (so the words were already defined before creating the first dummy to forget). i don't think creating multiple dummies will help here actually, every declaration happens in stage 0, and it would probably only flood the dictionary, your first approach worked fine (with the `FORGET` addition)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ATLAST is a primitive Forth, that doesn't allow you to go to a more sophisticated handling of sources. But all is not lost!

For example, a Forth implementation according to the ISO standard will handle the matter with ease with one or more of: **REQUIRE [IF] [THEN] [DEFINED] SRC >IN NAME WORD FIND**.

As you have a Forth, you can steal these words from another Forth and compile the code.

Another solution that may help directly is executing ***EXIT*** in interpret mode while loading a file.
You have to find out whether you can create a flag whether to abandon the input source.  Then this definition might help:

```
: ?abandon    IF S" EXIT" EVALUATE THEN ;
S" FIVE" FOUND ?abandon
```

Note that **?abandon** must be executed in interpret mode.